# python find sub tree minimum and maximum value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

I have a tree with nodes, in each node I have id, name, nodes, roles, parent_id and type.
I need to write a function that check in each nodes, if the nodes has roles, then find the minimum and maximum duration or the roles into the the roles.
after that I need to compare it with his parent(if it's not none), if the parent have maximum duration bigger then it so the children will get the maximum duration of parent/grandparent..
I'll add some examples and what I expected to get

```
 # example 1
roles_1 = [{id: 'r1', 'duration': 4}]
roles_2 = [{id: 'r2', 'duration': 5}, {id: 'r3', 'duration': 8}]

input_tree1 = {
    'nodes': [
        {
            'id': '1',
            'name': 'org1',
            'parent_id': None,
            'type': 'organization',
            'nodes': [
                {
                    'id': '2',
                    'name': 'o_folder_1',
                    'org_id': '1',
                    'parent_id': '1',
                    'type': 'folder',
                    'roles': roles_1,

                    'nodes': [
                        {
                            'id': '3',
                            'name': 'o1_f1_project_1',
                            'nodes': [],
                            'org_id': '1',
                            'parent_id': '2',
                            'type': 'project',
                            'roles': roles_2,
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a list of roles, each list of roles contains object of role. each role has id and duration.
in this example, I have parent **org1** with one child **o_folder_1** and one grandchild
**o1_f1_project_1**, what I need to do is tho check the grandchild if he has roles, if yes, I calculate the min and max duration of the sub tree, here is 8, then go level up calculate the roles if the node have , here is 4.. 4 is less than 8 so I need to add a update a new field of maximum_duration and minimum duration as you can see in expected tree:

```
  expected_tree1 = {'nodes': [
    {
        'id': '1',
        'name': 'org1',
        'parent_id': None,
        'type': 'organization',
        'nodes': [
            {
                'id': '2',
                'name': 'o_folder_1',
                'org_id': '1',
                'parent_id': '1',
                'type': 'folder',
                'roles': roles_1,
                'min_duration': 4,
                'max_duration': 4,
                'nodes': [
                    {
                        'id': '3',
                        'name': 'o1_f1_project_1',
                        'nodes': [],
                        'org_id': '1',
                        'parent_id': '2',
                        'type': 'project',
                        'roles': roles_2,
                        'min_duration': 4,
                        'max_duration': 8
                    }
                ],

            }
        ],
    }
]
}
```

as you can see here, I added new field of min_duration and maximum_duration for each node with the right value.
example 2:

```
  # example 2
roles_1 = [{id: 'r1', 'duration': 12}]
roles_2 = [{id: 'r2', 'duration': 4}, {id: 'r3', 'duration': 2}]
roles_3 = [{id: 'r4', 'duration': 5}]
roles_4 = [{id: 'r5', 'duration': 9}]

input_tree2 = {'nodes':
    [
        {
            'id': '1',
            'name': 'org1',
            'parent_id': None,
            'type': 'organization',
            'nodes':
                [
                    {
                        'id': '2',
                        'name': 'o1_folder_1',
                        'org_id': '1',
                        'parent_id': '1',
                        'type': 'folder',
                        'roles': roles_1,
                        'min_duration': 12,
                        'max_duration': 12
                        'nodes': [
                            {
                                'id': '3',
                                'name': 'o1_f1_project_1',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '2',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_2,

                            },
                            {
                                'id': '4',
                                'name': 'o1_f1_project_2',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '2',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_3,

                            },

                        ],
                    },

                    {
                        'id': '4',
                        'name': 'o1_folder_2',
                        'org_id': '1',
                        'parent_id': '1',
                        'type': 'folder',
                        'roles': roles_4,
                        'nodes': [
                            {
                                'id': '3',
                                'name': 'o1_f2_project1',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '4',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_3,
                            }
                        ],
                    },

                ],
        }]}
```

expected tree 2

```
  expected_tree2 = {'nodes':
    [
        {
            'id': '1',
            'name': 'org1',
            'parent_id': None,
            'type': 'organization',
            'nodes':
                [
                    {
                        'id': '2',
                        'name': 'o1_folder_1',
                        'org_id': '1',
                        'parent_id': '1',
                        'type': 'folder',
                        'roles': roles_1,
                        'min_duration': 12,
                        'max_duration': 12
                        'nodes': [
                            {
                                'id': '3',
                                'name': 'o1_f1_project_1',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '2',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_2,
                                'min_duration': 2,
                                'max_duration': 12
                            },
                            {
                                'id': '4',
                                'name': 'o1_f1_project_2',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '2',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_2,
                                'min_duration': 5,
                                'max_duration': 12
                            },
                        ],
                    },

                    {
                        'id': '4',
                        'name': 'o1_folder_2',
                        'org_id': '1',
                        'parent_id': '1',
                        'type': 'folder',
                        'roles': roles_4,
                        'min_duration': 9,
                        'max_duration': 9
                        'nodes': [
                            {
                                'id': '3',
                                'name': 'o1_f2_project1',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '4',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_3,
                                'min_duration': 5,
                                'max_duration': 9
                            }
                        ],
                    },

                ],
        }]}
```

example 3

```
 roles_1 = [{id: 'r1', 'duration': 18}]
roles_2 = [{id: 'r2', 'duration': 4}, {id: 'r3', 'duration': 2}]
roles_3 = [{id: 'r4', 'duration': 5}]
roles_4 = [{id: 'r5', 'duration': 9}, {id: 'r5', 'duration': 12}]
roles_5 = [{id: 'r6', 'duration': 20}]
input_tree3 = {'nodes':
    [
        {
            'id': '1',
            'name': 'org1',
            'parent_id': None,
            'type': 'organization',
            'roles': roles_1,
            'nodes':
                [
                    {
                        'id': '2',
                        'name': 'o1_folder_1',
                        'org_id': '1',
                        'parent_id': '1',
                        'type': 'folder',
                        'roles': roles_3,
                        'min_duration': 12,
                        'max_duration': 12,
                        'nodes': [
                            {
                                'id': '3',
                                'name': 'o1_f1_project_1',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '2',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_2,

                            },
                            {
                                'id': '4',
                                'name': 'o1_f1_project_2',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '2',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_2,

                            },

                        ],

                    },

                    {
                        'id': '4',
                        'name': 'o1_folder_2',
                        'org_id': '1',
                        'parent_id': '1',
                        'type': 'folder',
                        'roles': roles_5,
                        'nodes': [
                            {
                                'id': '3',
                                'name': 'o1_f2_project1',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '2',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_4,

                            }
                        ],

                    },

                ],
        }]}
```

expected tree 3

```
 expected_tree3 = {'nodes':
    [
        {
            'id': '1',
            'name': 'org1',
            'parent_id': None,
            'type': 'organization',
            'roles': roles_1,
            'min_duration': 18,
            'max_duration': 18,
            'nodes':
                [
                    {
                        'id': '2',
                        'name': 'o1_folder_1',
                        'org_id': '1',
                        'parent_id': '1',
                        'type': 'folder',
                        'roles': roles_3,
                        'min_duration': 5,
                        'max_duration': 18,
                        'nodes': [
                            {
                                'id': '3',
                                'name': 'o1_f1_project_1',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '2',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_2,
                                'min_duration': 2,
                                'max_duration': 18

                            },
                            {
                                'id': '4',
                                'name': 'o1_f1_project_2',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '2',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_2,
                                'min_duration': 2,
                                'max_duration': 18

                            },
                        ],

                    },

                    {
                        'id': '4',
                        'name': 'o1_folder_2',
                        'org_id': '1',
                        'parent_id': '1',
                        'type': 'folder',
                        'roles': roles_5,
                        'min_duration': 18,
                        'max_duration': 20,
                        'nodes': [
                            {
                                'id': '3',
                                'name': 'o1_f2_project1',
                                'nodes': [],
                                'org_id': '1',
                                'parent_id': '4',
                                'type': 'project',
                                'roles': roles_4,
                                'min_duration': 9,
                                'max_duration': 20

                            }
                        ],
                    },

                ],

        }]}
```

as you can see in the examples, each time I check in the last child if he has roles, if he has so it calculate the max duration, then compare with his parent if he has, if the parent has maximum duration it will get it.. but if not, the child only the child remain with the maximum duration, his parent will not effect by id and will not get the child duration..

assumptions:

- when parent_id is None is the root
- it can be with many levels (root->child->grandchild->....)
- if the root doesn't have roles so to check his children.
- root can be some children (not always binary tree)

actually what I'm tried to do it

```
def add_min_max_duration(tree:Dict):

for node in tree["nodes"]:
    if "roles" in node.keys():
        node["min_duration"] = 25
        node["max_duration"] = 0
        for role in node["roles"]:
            node["min_duration"] = min(node["min_duration"], role.duration)
            node["max_duration"] = max(node["max_duration"], role.duration)
    add_min_max_duration(node)
```

but it's not good because it's not compare with his parent/grandparent..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**data abstraction**

Start with a `min_max` data type with a `+` operation for combining two `min_max` instances -

```py
mm1 = min_max(2,5)
mm2 = min_max(3,9)
mm3 = mm1 + mm2    # (2, 9)
```

We could write it something like this -

```py
from math import inf

class min_max:
  def __init__(self, min = +inf, max = -inf):
    self.min = min
    self.max = max
  def __add__(self, other):
    return min_max(min(self.min, other.min), max(self.max, other.max))
```

**role_min_max**

We can compute the min_max of a role by writing `role_min_max` -

```py
def role_min_max(role):
  return iter_min_max(x["duration"] for x in role)
  
def iter_min_max(iterable):
  r = min_max()
  for value in iterable:
    r = r + min_max(value, value)
  return r
```

**tree_min_max**

Finally `tree_min_max` starts with a default min_max of `(-Infinity, Infinity)` and we `+` it to the `role_min_max` of the `tree["roles"]` value, if present. For all `node` of the children `tree["nodes"]`, we call `tree_min_max(node, mm)` with the updated min_max, `mm` -

```py
def tree_min_max(tree, mm = min_max()):
  if "roles" in tree:
    mm = mm + role_min_max(tree["roles"])
  return {
    "duration_min": mm.min,
    "duration_max": mm.max,
    **tree,
    "nodes": list(tree_min_max(node, mm) for node in tree["nodes"])
  }
```

**demo**

We will use `json` to pretty print the newly created tree -

```py
import json
print(json.dumps(tree_min_max(input_tree3), indent=2))
```

```py
{
  "duration_min": Infinity,
  "duration_max": -Infinity,
  "nodes": [
    {
      "duration_min": 18,
      "duration_max": 18,
      "id": "1",
      "name": "org1",
      "parent_id": null,
      "type": "organization",
      "roles": [
        {
          "id": "r1",
          "duration": 18
        }
      ],
      "nodes": [
        {
          "duration_min": 5,
          "duration_max": 18,
          "id": "2",
          "name": "o1_folder_1",
          "org_id": "1",
          "parent_id": "1",
          "type": "folder",
          "roles": [
            {
              "id": "r4",
              "duration": 5
            }
          ],
          "nodes": [
            {
              "duration_min": 2,
              "duration_max": 18,
              "id": "3",
              "name": "o1_f1_project_1",
              "nodes": [],
              "org_id": "1",
              "parent_id": "2",
              "type": "project",
              "roles": [
                {
                  "id": "r2",
                  "duration": 4
                },
                {
                  "id": "r3",
                  "duration": 2
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "duration_min": 2,
              "duration_max": 18,
              "id": "4",
              "name": "o1_f1_project_2",
              "nodes": [],
              "org_id": "1",
              "parent_id": "2",
              "type": "project",
              "roles": [
                {
                  "id": "r2",
                  "duration": 4
                },
                {
                  "id": "r3",
                  "duration": 2
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "duration_min": 18,
          "duration_max": 20,
          "id": "4",
          "name": "o1_folder_2",
          "org_id": "1",
          "parent_id": "1",
          "type": "folder",
          "roles": [
            {
              "id": "r6",
              "duration": 20
            }
          ],
          "nodes": [
            {
              "duration_min": 9,
              "duration_max": 20,
              "id": "3",
              "name": "o1_f2_project1",
              "nodes": [],
              "org_id": "1",
              "parent_id": "2",
              "type": "project",
              "roles": [
                {
                  "id": "r5",
                  "duration": 9
                },
                {
                  "id": "r5",
                  "duration": 12
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note, your `role_*` data should put `id` in quotes, otherwise the key for the dictionary is actually the `id` function, not the string `"id"` like you are probably intending.

Also note there was a hard-code `"min_duration"` and `"max_duration"` in the input provided which I removed here in this post.

To remove the `duration_min` and `duration_max` from the root note, we can add a special case for when `"roles"` is not present in the node -

```py
def tree_min_max(tree, mm = min_max()):
  if "roles" in tree:
    mm = mm + role_min_max(tree["roles"])
    return {
      "duration_min": mm.min,
      "duration_max": mm.max,
      **tree,
      "nodes": list(tree_min_max(node, mm) for node in tree["nodes"])
    }
  else:
    return {
      **tree,
      "nodes": list(tree_min_max(node, mm) for node in tree["nodes"])
    }
```

**without the min_max class**

We could write `min_max` as a simple function which takes two tuples and outputs a tuple of the combined minimums and maximums -

```py
def min_max(a, b):
  (amin, amax) = a
  (bmin, bmax) = b
  return min(amin, bmin), max(amax, bmax)
```

Then we update `iter_min_max` -

```py
def iter_min_max(iterable):
  r = (+inf, -inf)
  for value in iterable:
    r = min_max(r, (value, value))
  return r
```

In `tree_min_max` we need to initialize `mm` to the default min-max and if `"roles"` is present, update `mm` with the computed `role_min_max`. Notice because `mm` is no longer a class, we cannot access the subfields, `mm.min` and `mm.max`. Instead `mm` is a tuple and the fields are `mm[0]` and `mm[1]` -

```py
def tree_min_max(tree, mm = (+inf, -inf)):
  if "roles" in tree:
    mm = min_max(mm, role_min_max(tree["roles"]))
  return {
    "duration_min": mm[0],
    "duration_max": mm[1],
    **tree,
    "nodes": list(tree_min_max(node, mm) for node in tree["nodes"])
  }
```

This is more cognitive load on the programmer and they need to be careful to initialize a min-max with `(+inf, -inf)` manually. Using the class avoids this burden and makes it less likely for a mistake to occur.

Comment: Hey, first thanks for your response..  I run your answered. when the node have no roles so I don't want to add him duration_min and duration_max fields.  in you code it add fields. how can I remove it in this case?

Comment: no problem :D your comment basically says how to do it "when a node has no roles, then ..." is the same as `if not "roles" in node: return ... else: return ...`

Comment: @Manspof I added an edit at the bottom that would show you how to do that. I also removed `map` in favor of list comprehension. I think the code is more readable this way.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you. I really appreciate.. I have two questions, how the compare between grandparent and grandson works in this way? is there any way to do it without class min_max? with a function?

Comment: for each level of the tree, a new min_max `mm` is computed and passed down to all children in the `tree_min_max(node, mm)` call. you can do it without the `min_max` class but a well-defined data type is favourable in this case. i updated the post with an example.